# How to select all the item in Gridview and get the all item?

Tags: android, gridview, position

I read the file in the `SDcard/folder-A` and show the all file in `folder-A` on `Gridview`.

I implement the `multiple choose` in this `Gridview` , and I set a button name `selectAll`.

When I click this  `selectAll Button` , it will select all the item on the RridView?

**First Question:**

But I don't know how to write the code of `select All item` in the `selectAll Button`.

**Second Question:**

I get the position when I select the item , and I want to know the **total number of item** in the GridView.

How can I get the **total number of item** in the `Gridview` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select all items, you will have to call `setItemChecked()` in a loop for every item. You can get the item count from the `getCount()` method.

Comment: Thanks its working : gridview.setItemChecked(10,true);